# Setting headers on HttpServletResponse after writing response body

Tags: java, servlets, http-headers

I figured out the hard way that it isn't possible to add more headers to an `HttpServletResponse` after beginning to write the response body to the output buffer, which, I guess in some random universe could make sense even though everything is still just buffered in memory.

Now the question is: Is there some trick to circumvent this somehow? Clearly, since the function `resetBuffer()` is available, which allows clearing of the content body without clearing the headers, there must be some way for the `HttpServletResponse` object to return to the state where writing more headers was possible. Is there, for example, a way to read the content body, clearing it with `resetBuffer()`, setting more headers, and then restoring the content body?

***Aside**:
The reason I would like do this is so I can add a header as the preferably very last step in my servlet, which tells me how long the server was busy processing the request.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your only choice is to buffer the response body yourself; when body is finished, you then add the header, then write the body.

The funny thing is, HTTP/1.1 has a way to ship a header after the response body, by using trailer in chunked encoding, but nobody implements that, so don't bother.

Comment: All my further research points to you being correct, unfortunately.